# How can I check the mouse's position over a 2D array of images for a game?

Tags: java, mouseevent, multidimensional-array

Okay so I am creating a Candy Crush game replica in Java.
My problem lies in trying to create an event listener for clicking or hovering over the objects. I have tried different methods from using ImageIcons and using event listeners to now using JLabels and using icons and trying to determine if the JLabel is clicked.

What I am trying now is to use Rectangles and hitboxes like so:

```
public Rectangle mouseHitBox(MouseEvent e)
{
    int x = (int)e.getLocationOnScreen().getX(); //Grab Mouse X Coordinate and set it as an Int
    int y = (int)e.getLocationOnScreen().getY(); //Grab Mouse Y Coordinate and set it as an Int
    mouse.setBounds(x,y,1,1); //Create Mouse Hitbox

    return mouse; //Return it for Mouse Event
}

public Rectangle gemHitBox()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) //For loops to access all 81 gem images
        {
            int x = gemImage[i][j].getX(); // Get X coordinate of that specific array destination
            int y = gemImage[i][j].getY(); // Get Y coordinate of that specific array destination
            gem.setBounds(x,y,50,47); // Gem Hitbox
        }
    }
    return gem; //Return it for Mouse Event
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

   if(mouseHitBox(e).intersects(gemHitBox())) // If the Mouse Hitbox comes in contact with one of the array positions then
   {
      //Prepare to Swap Gems
   }


}
```

The Main Class implements MouseListener which is why I can just have a public void mouseClicked.

No matter what code is contatined in the mouse listeners, it ALWAYS has thrown this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Game.mouseHitBox(Game.java:125) //this line: mouse.setBounds(x,y,1,1);
at Game.mouseClicked(Game.java:147) //this line:  if(mouseHitBox(e).intersects(gemHitBox()))
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have been stuck on this problem for three days and any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that mouseHitBox return something not null ?

The stacktrace seems to show that this method return null in this case.

Is mouse initialised in this case?

Comment: I figured out what I did, I did forget to initialize it. Thanks!